# coderush underline errors

Tags: c#, coderush

I am trying out coderush after spending a lot of time with resharper.  In resharper it is possible to underline all errors as you type.  Is this function available in coderush?  if so how do i turn it on?

Comment: Sounds like a question for their support team.

Comment: -1; this isn't a programming question; it's a CodeRush support question.

Comment: CodeRush is a programming tool like SQL, Resharper and Studio... It is programming related, hence a perfectly valid stack overflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called CodeIssues.

It is available only with the Full version of CodeRush. I mention this in case you are using the Xpress version.

It was introduced initially in version 9.1.x. So be sure you have at least this version.

I would always recommend getting the latest version. at the time of this answer this would be 9.3.2.

There are 2 ways to toggle CodeIssues on/off

1. The first Checkbox on the CodeIssues options page

---

Follow these steps to get to the Code Issues options page:

1. From the DevExpress menu, select "Options...".
2. In the tree view on the left, navigate to this folder:

   Editor\Code Analysis
3. Select the "Code Issues" options page.

---

2. User the first button on the DXCoreVisualize toolbar